# Error to import Mudole to android studio 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

i frist import Mudole and add these code to my project build.gradel

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}
```

and

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

but mudole build.gradle have errore

> Error:(2, 0) Cause:
>   org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory Open File

and this mudele gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

version = "1.2.0"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 5
        versionName version
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress'
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress.git'
group = "com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress"
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                // Add your description here
                name 'Circle Progress, Donut Progress, Arc Progress'
                url siteUrl
                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'MIT'
                        url 'http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'lzyzsd'
                        name 'Bruce Lee'
                        email 'bruceinpeking@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = "CircleProgress"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["MIT"]
        publish = true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

i download mudole from https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Comment: just change version gradle to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

**just change version gradle to 1.0**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update gradle plugin and version.

Update gradle plugin by Replacing

```
 apply plugin: 'android-maven'
```

with

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

and update gradle version by adding this :

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
```

and sync project.